# It seems to be generating a file, then "internal server error" when generating an .xls

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I do not know much about this, then I would appreciate if you help.
I'm trying to generate xls more than 2205 rows.

on my localhost, it takes 6 minutes to create the file. on my server after 2 minutes an error.

[image]
in my localhost it works fine, but not on my server. this is my server settings.
 [image]

Comment: Check your server logs

Comment: hard to tell without the code. Maybe there's a memory problem... Can you enable error-codes on your script?

Comment: are you using fast cgi?

Comment: @MarkBaker  No error is generated in the log for this problem ..in my localhost it takes 6 minutes and the file is generated, on my server does not end

Comment: @Adam what is that? no, i dont use..

Comment: @patrick no problems with the code, I think the problem is because there is a lot of information

Comment: Can you try to write just a one-row file to see if file size is really an issue?